# Renaming indexes and constraints dynamically via script

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have some unnamed constraints on the table that start with `SYS_`. I want to name them conventionally with TABLENAME_CONSTRAINTTYPE, for example instead of `SYS_C12345` I want to name it `MyTable1_PK`

Now, the issue is that I need to do that in multiple environments and the name of the constraint differs from environment to environment. So I cannot hard-code anything as the same script will run in all environments.

I figured out a way to get the constraint name dynamically based on column name and constraint type:

```
SELECT acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM   ALL_CONS_COLUMNS acc
   INNER JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS ac
   ON ( acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME )
WHERE  ac.OWNER        = 'SCHEMA1'
AND    ac.TABLE_NAME   = 'MY_TABLE1'
AND    acc.COLUMN_NAME = 'MY_ID'
AND    ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P') 
AND acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'SYS_%'
```

but I'm having trouble integrating it with the rename sql:

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA1.MY_TABLE1 RENAME CONSTRAINT '' TO MY_TABLE1_PK;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you doing this in a plsql block?

Comment: You will have to do this in a plsql block or stored procedure, because `ALTER TABLE` is not SQL. It is DDL, which can't be mixed with SQL directly.

Comment: If you're renaming primary key constraints you might want to think about renaming their supporting indexes too (assuming they are default ones built as part of the constraint creation process).

Comment: @APC, thanks, that is exactly what i am doing. First renaming the indexes, then the constraints

Comment: By the way, there are no brackets in a `join` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `execute immediate` within a PL/SQL code block inside a loop as below

```
begin
  for c in (
            SELECT acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME, ac.TABLE_NAME, ac.OWNER
              FROM   ALL_CONS_COLUMNS acc
             INNER JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS ac
                ON ( acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME )
             WHERE  ac.OWNER        = 'SCHEMA1'
               AND  ac.TABLE_NAME   = 'MY_TABLE1'
               AND  acc.COLUMN_NAME = 'MY_ID'
               AND  ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P') 
               AND acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'SYS_%'
            )
  loop
    execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE '||c.OWNER||'.'||c.TABLE_NAME||' RENAME CONSTRAINT 
                      '||c.CONSTRAINT_NAME||' TO '||c.TABLE_NAME||'_pk';
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: and I can just embed this into my script in BEGIN...END; block?

Comment: @CodingDuchess exactly, excuse me forgetting to add.

Comment: thank you! one more thing. What if I am doing the same to other types of constraints `ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('C')` and there is more than one constraint on the column. Is there a way to handle renaming those?

Comment: @CodingDuchess you're welcome. Sure, the same logic works again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an SP and call it with the right parameters.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp_update_constraints(p_schema_name IN VARCHAR2,
                                              p_table_name  IN VARCHAR2,
                                              p_column_name IN VARCHAR2) IS
CURSOR constraint_name_cur(p_schema_name VARCHAR2,
                           p_table_name  VARCHAR2,
                           p_column_name VARCHAR2) IS
    SELECT acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM   ALL_CONS_COLUMNS acc
       INNER JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS ac
       ON ( acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME )
    WHERE  ac.OWNER        = p_schema_name
    AND    ac.TABLE_NAME   = p_table_name
    AND    acc.COLUMN_NAME = p_column_name
    AND    ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P') 
    AND acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'SYS_%';
BEGIN
FOR cn IN constraint_name_cur(p_schema_name, p_table_name, p_column_name) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ALTER TABLE ' || p_schema_name || '.' || p_table_name || ' RENAME CONSTRAINT ' || cn.constraint_name || ' TO ' || p_table_name ||'_PK');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || p_schema_name || '.' || p_table_name || ' RENAME CONSTRAINT ' || cn.constraint_name || ' TO ' || p_table_name ||'_PK';
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: cannot use this as this will be a part of a large script